# Heroku deploy failled

Tags: deployment

{
"name": "offres",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "node server.js",
"build": "ng build",
"watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
"test": "ng test",
"heroku-postbuild": "ng build --configuration production"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^16.1.0",
"@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
"@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
"@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.1.2",
"@coreui/angular": "^4.5.27",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.2.0",
"bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
"express": "^4.18.2",
"firebase": "^9.23.0",
"jquery": "^3.7.0",
"jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^10.3.0",
"ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
"ngx-pagination": "^6.0.3",
"ngx-slick-carousel": "^15.0.0",
"ngx-star-rating": "^2.1.0",
"ngx-toastr": "^17.0.2",
"owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"primeicons": "^4.1.0",
"primeng": "^15.0.0",
"rxjs": "^7.4.0",
"script-loader": "^0.7.2",
"slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
"sweetalert2": "^11.6.13",
"tinymce": "^6.6.2",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.13.0"
},
"engines": {
"node": "18.18.2",
"npm": "10.2.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.7",
"@angular/cli": "~15.2.7",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
"jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
"karma": "~6.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
"typescript": "~4.9.4"
}
}